# Building complex tables and get the innerXML

Tags: javascript, xml, datatables, frontend, openxml

I am asking the question here because i don't know a better place to ask, basicly i am buidling a aplication(frontend and backend) that should create and edit documents (at the moment just .docx). So basicly everytime i want to create a simple table i drag the element and put some configurations, like this:

[image: configuration]

after this i can send it to the backend and append it to the document using openxml, my problem with this approach is that i can't(actually it is possible but to complex) build complex tables with merges and insert text to cells.

what i need to know, is if there is a good way to do this (maybe a JS lib or something) i searched a lot didn't find anything useful at the moment.

Any tip? need something that in the end i can extract to xml

Comment: Have you checked : https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen-docx-table#a4

Comment: actually i am searching a front end solution that let me build the table in a dynamic way, the backend solution is already in openxml and is working good